# Disable trimming of whitespace from path variables in Spring 3.2

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

By default, Spring trims leading/trailing whitespace from strings used as path variables. I've tracked this down to be because the *trimTokens* flag is set to *true* by default in **AntPathMatcher**.

What I can't figure out, though, is how to set that flag to *false*.

Providing my own **RequestMappingHandlerMapping** bean using an **AntPathMatcher** where I set it to *false* didn't work.

How do I change this flag using JavaConfig?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide an example URL? Did you encode your URLs (`[space]` --> `%20`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let your configuration extend `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` override `requestMappingHandlerMapping()` and configure accordingly.

```
@Configuration
public MyConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    @Bean
    public PathMatcher pathMatcher() {
      // Your AntPathMatcher here.
    }

    @Bean
    public RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping() {
        RequestMappingHandlerMapping  rmhm = super.requestMappingHandlerMapping();
        rmhm.setPathMatcher(pathMatcher());
        return rmhm;
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked, thanks!

I was extending WebMvcConfigurerAdapter and not WebMvcConfigurationSupport.

Comment: Starting with spring 4.0.3 you can also override `configurePathMatch()` to set a path matcher.

Answer (score 1):

## The problem

Just like you pointed out the issue is because all versions of the [Spring Framework before 4.3.0 have the default antPathMatcher](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v4.3.0.RELEASE/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/util/AntPathMatcher.java) with the **trimTokens** flag is set to true.

## Solution

Add a config file that returns the default antPathMatcher but with the **trimTokens** flag set to false

```
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class PricingConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

  @Bean
  public PathMatcher pathMatcher() {

    AntPathMatcher pathMatcher = new AntPathMatcher();
    pathMatcher.setTrimTokens(false);
    return pathMatcher;
  }

  @Override
  public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {        
    configurer.setPathMatcher(pathMatcher());
  }
}
```